# how to construct a tree from a tree without recursion

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have a tree of Mangoes items, and for every item i want to apply a treatment to turn them into Apples, how can i write a method (in Java will be nice) which takes the top of the mangoes tree element and return the top of an apples Tree without recursion.

With recursion i have something like this:

```
Apple transform(Mangoe ma){      
    //Construct an apple from some modified mangoes properties
    Apple ap = new Apple(...);  
    List<Apple> apChildren = new ArrayList<Apple>();
    for(Mangoe maChild:ma.getChildren())
        children.add(transform(maChild));  
    ap.setChildren(children);  
    return ap;
}
```

How can i repeat this behaviour with a method without recursion??

EDIT:
i was thinking about this algorithm to solve the problem:

```
List<Mangoe> itemsToTreat = new ArrayList<Mangoe>();
itemsToTreat.add(ma);

while(itemsToTreat!=null){
     //Apply treatment
     //it's impossible to set the child of a created apple without recursion         

     //get the direct children of itemsToTreat
     itemsToTreat = getDirectChildrenOfItemsToTreat(itemsToTreat);


}
```

Comment: In most cases you can replace recursive calls with loops and some sort of stack, e.g. have a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/08/01/recursion-part-two-unrolling-a-recursive-function-with-an-explicit-stack/). After all, recursive method calls do the same: they just put another call of the same method on a call stack along with some information on the parameters etc.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by recursion. You can write a recursive process as a iterative loop with help from a heap allocated data structure to handle the recursion rather than the system stack. You cannot do it without any kind of recursive process since that would require that every node of the tree never had more than one child, thus a linked list.

Comment: In case you are using `Tree` structure, I'm afraid you'll have to use recursion, either hidden or explicitly. For example, in case you are using `TreeSet` you may get its iterator and go through all the elements with `while` loop. However inside iterator there will be multiple recursive calls to `TreeMap.successor(Entry<K,V> t)` method

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not so fluent in Java at the moment, I will use some Java-like pseudocode and some explanations. The problem can be solved by means a user-defined stacks as follows. The key is to store some information where to store the generated results, which is done implicitly on the call stack in the recursive implementation; this is done with the following auxiliary class which stores just enough information.

```
class AugmentedMangoe
{
    public Mango iMangoe;      // Mangoe to convert
    public Apple iParentApple; // place where to add it as child after conversion

    public AugmentedMangoe(Mangoe iMangoe, Apple iParentApple)
    {
        iMangoe = iMangoe;
        iParentApple = iParentApple;
    }
}
```

The actual iterative process is done via `iStack` which models the recursion.

```
Apple transform(Mangoe ma)
{
    Apple Result = null;
    Stack<AugmentedMangoe> iStack = new Stack<AugmentedMangoe>();
    iStack.push(new AugmentedMangoe(ma, null));
    while (iStack.hasElements())
    {
        // get current Mangoe
        Mangoe iCurrentMangoe = iStack.pop();

        // convert Mangoe to Apple and save it
        Apple iCurrentApple = new Apple(iCurrentMangoe.iMangoe);

        // store the converted root, which is done only in the first iteration
        Result = null != Result ? Result : iCurrentApple;

        // put children to the stack
        for(Mangoe iChild:iCurrentMangoe.iMangoe.getChildren())
            iStack.push(new AugmentedMangoe(iChild, iCurrentApple));

        // if we have stored where to put the converted object to, put it there
        if (null != iCurrentMangoe.iParentApple)
            iCurrentMangoe.iParentApple.addChild(iCurrentApple);
    }
    return Result:
}
```

Shouldn't it be *Mango* instead of *Mangoe*, supposed that [magnifera indica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangifera_indica) is meant?